# Visual proofs of $1^3+2^3+3^3+\dots+n^3=(1+2+3+\dots+n)^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, recreational-mathematics, visualization

I was solving a problem that uses the fact: $1^3+2^3+\dots+n^3=(1+2+\dots+n)^2$. I know that this can be proved by induction or using $1^3+2^3+\dots+n^3=\left\{\frac{(n(n+1)}{2}\right\}^2$. But I am interested in visual proofs.

One idea to prove this visually is to show that the sum of the volumes of the cubes with side lengths $1,2,3,\dots,n$ equals to the area of a square with side length $(1+2+3+\dots+n)$. This idea also appeared in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2137983) which checks the validity of the idea just for small cases. So, completing this idea or some other ideas to prove this visually is highly appreciated.

(The question on finding a proof of the statement has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294213/prove-that-13-23-n3-1-2-n2). But I didn't find any visual proof apart from the one I mentioned.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formalize a proof without words of the identity $(1 + 2 + \cdots + n)^2 = 1^3 + 2^3 + \cdots + n^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089990/formalize-a-proof-without-words-of-the-identity-1-2-cdots-n2-13) or [Proving the identity $\sum_{k=1}^n {k^3} = \big(\sum_{k=1}^n k\big)^2$ without induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/proving-the-identity-sum-k-1n-k3-big-sum-k-1n-k-big2-without-i?noredirect=1&lq=1) also

Comment: @Infinity_hunter That really does. Thanks and sorry for posting a duplicate.